# Prevent Symfony's CheckboxType casting strings to bool

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, boolean

I am working on a Symfony 5.4 REST API and validating a user's input using FormTypes. I have a required  boolean field and would like to **throw a form exception if I receive any non-boolean input for that field**. However, Symfony's CheckboxType automatically sets any non-boolean input to `true` when I submit the form, so I can not check if my input was a legit boolean.

My code looks like this:

```
        $inputModel= new InputModel();
        $this->form->setData($inputModel);
        if ($this->request->isMethod('PUT')) {
            // Here the vaue of $this->request->request->all()['myBooleanField'] is "asdf"
            $this->form->submit($this->request->request->all());
            // Here the value of inputModel->getMyBooleanField() is true
            //...
        }
```

My FormType `buildForm` method looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        //...
        ->add('myBooleanField', typeForm\CheckboxType::class, [ 'required' => true ])
        //...
        ;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This seems like correct behaviour to me. The Checkbox field is either *true* or *false*. If the user types anything then that is deemed as *true*. Not sure how you have this setup, how is the user inputting the data, via a form or json?

Comment: Hi @Bossman the data is sent to the API as json in the request body. I understand this is the standard behaviour, but in my case I would prefer to catch that and throw a validation error, do you think it is possible?

Comment: If that is the case then don't use the form builder, just handle the type check in your controller for that particular route.. You could use [is_bool](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-bool.php) for example, if its not throw your error..